# Intel MIC - sum of intrinsic vector elements

Tags: c++, simd, intel-mic, avx512

I have a __m512d intrinsic vector and I need sum of his elements. Is there any easy way to do this? I am concentrated on a performance of computation, so i need to do this operation quickly. My knowledge about intrinsic is not enough to do it yourself, so I need Your help.

Thanks :)

Comment: BTW, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896432/horizontal-add-with-m512-avx512) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following intrinsic should help you:

```
double _mm512_reduce_add_pd (__m512d a)
```

P.S. You can look for useful intrinsics in [the guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/) yourself.

Comment: I was looking for on this site, but i didn't see this. Thanks a lot.